# Взаимодействие через websocket между приложениями на tomcat и wildfly

Tags: java, websocket

Всем привет!
Изучаю Java относительно недавно. В целях обучения написал небольшое приложение, состоящее из двух модулей:
1. Spring+Hibernate данные в базе MySQL, отображение на JSP, деплой на Tomcat.
2. EJB, данные берутся из той же самой базы, деплой на WildFly.
У меня возник такой вопрос: каким образом настроить взаимодействие двух модулей через websocket? 
Например: первый вносит какие-то изменения в базу, посылает уведомление на второй, он подтягивает из базы свежие данные и отображает их пользователю.
Почитал разные мануалы, посмотрел примеры, но не нашел чего-то похожего.
Не совсем понимаю с чего начать. Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вряд ли придумали стандартное использование вебсокетов для такой задачи. Но найдёт кучу примеров restful, web-сервисов или тот же ejb без всяких web-оболочек. Самое модное - restful сервисы

Comment: Websocket - неподходящий для этого протокол. Сделать можно, но это будет костыль.

Comment: В Spring хорошо реализован сервер для WebSoket. Материала по теме навалом. Клиент Spring тоже есть. Но, если использовать websocket для больших сообщений, придется немного поковыряться с настройками сервера и заголовков на клиенте. В любом случае, если нужно сделать длительную асинхронную обработку, этот метод обладает рядом весомых приемуществ перед long polling или rest callback, но и недостатки имеются.